# large database file (mdb) takes time to load in vb.net so need alternative

Tags: database, vb.net, database-design, ms-access, rtf

I have 4k records in access database. And one of the field value contains ~100 lines each 
so and one other field has ~25 lines. So total database size reaches ~30MB and it takes lot of time 15-20 seconds to load the database in vb.net using odbc http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets12p5.html

and updating of any other small fields also takes time due to database being large

So as an alternative I used rtf file (txt files were not preserving all the newline characters). So these file are around 5-10kb only. But for 4k records and 2 fields I have now 8k files. And copying of these 8k rtf files is taking huge time for 5MB transfer it takes an hour or so.

So is there any other alternative for storage of this data. So that it will be portable and easily loaded/accessed/updated from vb.net?

Comment: An hour to transfer 5MB is an unbelievable amount of time! Where are you transferring from and to?

Comment: I know it sounds unbelievable, but its true and that is why i had to ask this question. Details: I zipped 8k rtf files (which also took half an hour) and then shared it with friend for whom it took an hour to unzip those files.Both of us are using Thinkpad w510

Comment: Are all copies and zips so slow? It may be worth asking about this on superuser.

Comment: Are you using memo fields or OLE fields to store the multi-line data? I think you should post some of your code. It seems whatever you are doing is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MDB Databases**

[image]

MDB is the Access database filetype.  Access databases were never designed to be used for backends of web systems, they are mainly for light office use.

**Improving performance**

For temporary improvement of performance, you can compact and repair the database.  Open it up, and find the link in the tools menu.  Alternatively you can do this [programaticaly](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306287).  This should be done reasonably frequently depending on the number of changes your databases has made to it.  [What does compact and repairing do?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209769/EN-US/)

Also, slowness is often a sign of inefficient design.  Consider reading up on [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if your database is not fully normalised.  This should significantly improve performance and is an essential standard that should be learned.

**Alternatives**

For 4k+ records you should probably be using a decent database system designed specifically for larger amounts of data.

SQL-Server is an excellent database system from Microsoft.  MySQL is also a great open source alternative.  The Internet is full of tutorials on how to connect to these databases.

Comment: I do not see "backends of web systems" in the OP? I think one of the problems is that it seems to be used for storing documents, which is not a good idea, I think some people say even SQL Server is not the best place for documents. If a document must be stored in Access, BLOBs or Acess 2010 would be the best bet.

Comment: using compact and repair option in ms-access has significantly reduced the size of the database. Its now 6.5MB from earlier 30MB. Thanks a lot for suggesting this option. Now time required to start and update is acceptable and I will not need to have so many files.

Comment: But even 30MBs and 4K records is trivial for Access. There's obviously something else going on that is not being fully revealed.

Comment: I don't think this is a useful answer at all. It doesn't really address any of the issues, none of which seem to me to be Access/Jet/ACE-specific. Indeed, it seems that the problem is with the data access method, since within Access itself, manipulating this minuscule amount of data would be trivial (and near instantaneous).

Comment: @David How can you say it didn't address any of the issues when the compact and repair option has resolved the issue for the question asker?  I misunderstood the context apparently, but 4k records that get modified a lot and are never compact and repaired will cause loads of issues.  I've had less records that ran incredibly badly because they weren't compact and repaired before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using sometimes Access databases in .net too. Ok, MS-Access isn't the best database for this kind of application, I know. But the easy-doing complex queryes and the functional and well-knowed reports makes Access a good cost-benefit solution.

I saw the link that you've indicated. This way was my first technique, but then I realized there was another easier and faster. I suggest you to do the linkage for Access database in a different way.

1. Create a dataSet, if you already didn't it.
2. Create a connection to the MS-Access database using database explorer.
3. Drag and drop your desired tables on created DataSet (.net will create the designer code for you in backStage)
4. On code, create an tableAdapter object and a table object:
   Supose that your dataSet name is DS1 and a table name is table01.

   language: VB.NET
   check intellisense autocomplete for your dataobjects

creates a tableadapter object and table object (designed when you drop the database explorer objects in dataset)

```
dim table01_TA as new ds1Tableadapters.table01_tableAdapter
dim table01 as new ds1.table01dataTable
```

loads the database data into the on-memory table table01

```
table01 = table01_TA.getData
```

do your opperations using table01 (add, update, insert, delete, queries)
for automatic generation of scripts for update, insert and delete, make sure your table has primaryKeys and correct relationships. 
finally, update the table adapter. Unless you do it, the data will not be updated in the database.

```
table01_Ta.update(table01)
```

I suggest you use LINQ to query your data, and the datatable methods to adding and editing data. These methods are created automatically when you drop the databaseExplorer tables on dataSet and save it. Its worth to compact and repair Access database frequently.

Contat-me if you have troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom's recommendation. Get yourself a decent database server. However, judging by your description of your performance issues it seems like you have other serious problems which are probably going to be difficult to resolve here.

Comment: The amount of data described is incredibly trivial. The problem here is not Jet/ACE -- it's clearly something in the code being used to retreive/manipulate the data.

Comment: Well that's what I said too. A client-server DBMS is technically superior, solves related issues and obviously has enormous advantages over a file-sharing model like Jet. Given that the OP is using .NET anyway and offered no explanation of why he would use Jet, it's perfectly sensible to point out that it probably isn't the best choice he could have made.

Comment: That's all well and good, but you pollute your answer with the phrase "decent database server." Why not just say "get a server database back end, instead of using a file-based back end." That's completely neutral and can't be interpreted as slagging on Jet/ACE/Access.